# Trouble with Making UITableViewCells Dynamic

Tags: objective-c, ios, dynamic, uitableview

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell called Comment, which has a UILabel containing some relevant information. This information is of varying length, so it is merely impossible for me to set a appropriate height for the UILabel.

I have tried making the cell dynamic, but the UILabel either overflows the cell (y axis) or the cell is too big.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?!

```
tableView... cellForRowAtIndexPath...

[cell->commentText setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[cell->commentText setMinimumFontSize:14];
[cell->commentText setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell->commentText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

NSString *text = [cell->commentText text];

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320, 20000.0f);

CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

[cell->commentText setText:text];
[cell->commentText setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 280, MAX(size.height, 125))];


- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *text = [[[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] body] stringByStrippingHTML];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320, 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 125);

    return height + 20;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you stripping the html in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`also?

I've dynamically resized labels two different ways which have both worked:

1) In IB, anchor the label to the top and bottom of the cell and set its height to flexible (under the ruler icon in the right side panel). Then, just implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as you've done.

2) In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set the label's width and then call `[label sizeToFit]`. Use your same `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.